# Blazor WASM app - SQL Server role-based authorization using OKTA as Identity Provider

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, okta, role-base-authorization

I am able to create the authentication using OKTA for a Blazor WASM application I am working on. Using this link (https://clearmeasure.com/blazor-webassembly-okta/) as a guide the Authentication setup.

Next step is to implement the role-based authorization on the application by doing a user data verification with the SQL Server database for the authenticated user. On a successful verification by user email, the authenticated user is granted authorization for the role assigned to them in the database.

The authorization MUST be managed outside of OKTA in SQL Server. The information of the OKTA authenticated user is already stored in the database which includes the user-role and email address.

Kindly advise on what is the recommended secured approach to manage the role-based authorization for about 5 different user roles (one user can only have one role at a time).